# how to convert Record to another Record with different keys in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function `convert`, its parameter is an object, the value can be function or an object contains three properties, the type looks like this.

```
type Input = {
  [K: string]: () => any | { pending: () => any, fulfilled: () => any, rejected: {} => any }
}
```

I hope can return an object, that the keys will generate by the values, for example:

```
const result = convert({
  sync() {},
  async: {
    pending() {},
    fulfilled() {},
    rejected() {}
  }
});
// the keys of result
result.sync();
result.asyncPending();
result.asyncFulfilled();
result.asyncRejected();
```

currently, I know how to generate result by the keys and the string literals

```
type Result<Input> = {
  [key in keyof Input as `${string & key}Fulfilled`]: any
}
```

but can't meet my requirement, I google for a long time, but can't found the solution.

Comment: Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAKgPw). However, @Tobias S. was faster

Comment: Thank you too!! your `Convert` type make it easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposed solution would look like this:

```
type Input = {
  [key: string]: { pending: () => any, fulfilled: () => any, rejected: () => any } | (() => any)
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Result<Input> = {
  [K in keyof Input as Input[K] extends () => any ? K : never]: Input[K]
} & UnionToIntersection<{
  [K in keyof Input]: { 
    [K2 in keyof Input[K] as `${K & string}${Capitalize<K2 & string>}`]: Input[K][K2] 
  }
}[keyof Input]> extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never

function convert<T extends Input>(arg: T): Result<T> {
    return {} as any
}
```

For each property `K` of `Input` where the type is an object we map over the keys in `Input[K]`. For each key `K2` inside `Input[K]`, we rename the key to `${K & string}${Capitalize<K2 & string>}` and return the type `Input[K][K2]`. The resulting mapped object is converted to a union by indexing it with `keyof Input`.

This union can be converted to an intersection with `UnionToIntersection` to get all nested keys a level higher.

Now `result` has the correct type:

```
const result = convert({
  sync() {},
  async: {
      pending() {},
      fulfilled() {},
      rejected() {}
  }
});
// const result: {
//     sync: () => void;
//     asyncPending: () => void;
//     asyncFulfilled: () => void;
//     asyncRejected: () => void;
// }

result.sync();
result.asyncPending();
result.asyncFulfilled();
result.asyncRejected();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAUFKBtAawhAC4oBnYAJwEs4BzAXTIykjgBM76yAKASjQA%20KAEM4IADRQAZogA2MmvPkQOfQahHipUKhABWEAMbA1G4WIlQAvlAA%20UXgMs7%20WG1iyhIUAKpwNAD2cAAqQfBmVOQmwMFwADx%20Iug4Tn5QEAAeZpzkViBQAPxOBGR%20-FoAbkE0HFBkcBBVEFSC2bkc%20c5lUHQyrbCVQjV1giUwDVBNLVRePtAAShDkCsAJ8EjAKZhpeADSfXBQRCBBMrAIyGL5m8gHjJk5EHlOmtrWJYeNza3Ml1sHh4oAAyfyBELhSKtGKmeIJbC4A5HE7Ec4A5D-VhpJH7ABMKNO6LuwAeNygAAMACQYQ5gyi0Bg2GkAYVEYBowFE8hoAC8IAl8aCKNRuEIbBT-iSHgc8Y80p4bIQ0RcSYwRB0Xl0jgMqFAAPLFTD4Q50VFnC76-76sl2H6zLxyOBwkJQYwhWbrUJPTq3K7bXiiKg8KChfhkZareRekSI3B6CDARBUY4YOyifI6Dxed1wSgJqModC5z28OPkEDOlxpyRpDOV4wsHHx9hcBjVmy1%20PxuSKZSqDgdrvdhNGUxqDsKjz8ADcXn0hYAdBWq7OsAu1ov686AApa7gCOcb6NblfGABiCiUKgna%20PwFPDeWY7Mg9nQA)

Comment: thank you so much, what a magic of this `UnionToIntersection `, though I still confuse, I am new for TS, let me think more about this, thanks again!

Comment: @JanGao [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286) you can find an explanation for UnionToIntersection type. You are right, it is a magic :D